# git backup a remote repository with another remote

Tags: bash, git, shell, tfs, tfs-2015

I have a remote repository on github and another remote repository for backup.
Since the repository is very big I don't want everytime to use git push --mirror (it is above 20GB) and want to sync only latest changes everytime.

I want to write a script that is doing something like this:

```
for each branch in githubRemote/branches do:
  if branch != otherRemote/branch:
     checkout githubRemote/branch
     push branch to otherRemote
```

Comment: Why don't you just run `git fetch origin` on the backup repo system? Git already takes care of only transferring what is missing. If that doesn't work for you maybe provide more information about your exact setup/situation.

Comment: The other remote is on TFS 2015 server. I don't think I have a direct access to the repository

Comment: @FelixKling what else do you need to know about the setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on @Levi Lu-MSFT's answer, I wrote this script:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard

$branches = git branch -r  | foreach{ $_ -replace "^.*?\/", "" } | where {$_ -notmatch "HEAD" }
 
foreach($branch in $branches)
{
   
    $branchBackupHash = git rev-parse remoteTFS/$branch
    $branchWorkingHash = git rev-parse remoteGithub/$branch
    #check if the commit hash is the same
    if($branchBackupHash -ne $branchWorkingHash)
    {
      echo updating branch $branch
      git checkout origin/$branch -q
      git pull origin $branch
      git push remoteTFS $branch
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out below example in powershell scripts:

```
git clone htpp://githubRemote/repoName -q #clone remote repository on github

cd repoName 

$branches = git branch -r  | foreach{ $_ -replace "^.*?\/", "" } | where {$_ -notmatch "HEAD" }
 
foreach($branch in $branches)
{
    git checkout $branch -q
    $message = git pull origin 

    if($message -ne "Already up to date.")
    {
      git push http://PAT@tfs2015:8081/tfs/DefaultCollection/project/_git/repo $branch
    
     #you can also use your username:password as credentials
     #if your password or username contain @ replace it with %40
     #git push http://username:password@tfs2015:8081/tfs/DefaultCollection/project/_git/repo $branch 
     
    }
 }
```

Above script will clone the remote github repository and check out all the branches, then pull the latest codes from the remote github repository. If there are changes made to remote github branch, only these branch will be pushed to the other remote tfs repo.

If you use your tfs account username:password as credentials. Your account needs to have the permission to contribute to the remote tfs repo. Ask your tfs project admin to grant you the permission if you donot have the access.

You can also ask your tfs project admin give a [Personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-a-pat)(PAT) with code read/write scope. Then you can use the PAT as the credentials.

Comment: $branches = git branch -r  | foreach{ $_ -replace "^.*?\/", "" } | where {$_ -notmatch "HEAD" }' how does it know to check the changes from github remote? it means you need every time you run the script to clone?

Comment: Also, is there a way to check if the remoteA is different than remoteB without checkout and pull for all the branches? as I said, it is a very heavy repository

Comment: the clone command only needs to run at the first time. The pull command checks the changes from github remote. The first time to clone and pull will take some time. afterwards pull commands will pull only the changes and will take much less time. If you want to check only the changes, you probably will need to use checkout and then pull or fetch. Either way will take long time for the first time, but it will be much faster afterwards.

Comment: is there a safer way to check if there are differences rather than parsing the message (i.e. $message -ne "Already up to date.")? maybe comparing the hash values or something?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your backup repository and do `git fetch origin` or `git pull origin`.

Edit:
I don't know much about TFS, but maybe, you can schedule a task there?
If not, maybe it has an API which will trigger a `git pull` or `git fetch`, so you can write a script calls the right endpoint to do this and schedule it on some other machine.

Comment: see my comments to @FelixKling in the question